# Can not list Azure Devops directory in visual studio and from browser stuck on login screen

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I am not an expert on Azure DevOps but I created an organization, two users, and some GIT projects by reading some articles.

It was working until the last week for two users.

One day, the second user couldn't submit because he was disconnected.

Since we try to reconnect but impossible !!!

We are using Visual Studio 2022.

He is connected with his Microsoft account.

First of all, when he tries to clone an application, the azure server is not listed!

When we try to add it manually by clicking on the button Add Azure DevOps Server, it says that we must select a server from the list.

When he tries to connect via a browser, the login screen repeats an infinite loop.

I have changed the access type of the user but it doesn't change anything.

[image: Visual studio]
[image: Users]

[image: Project details]

Any idea, please?

Answer (score 0):

[Azure DevOps Server](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/server/): Previously known as Team Foundation Server (TFS), Azure DevOps Server is a set of collaborative software development tools, hosted on-premises.

It seems you are using Azure DevOps Service, you can check if clicking the arrow expands the "dev.azure.com", it should be show the organization name.

If not, please try to clean the cache of the visual studio and try it again.

[expand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZL0yB.png)

Comment: Hi Ging, thanks for your answer. On the second developer's PC, there is no dev.azure.com either. I change the image.

Comment: Have you tried to re-add the second user account to check if the account works on browser and Visual Studio 2022?

Comment: Yes, I removed the second user, re-sent the invitation, etc. It doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have another version of Visual Studio? Check if this problem is related to Visual Studio. And try to use the admin account. If the problem persists, please submit a feedbacon on the developer community: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=problem

Comment: I will try it on visual studio 2019.

Comment: By the way, the only thing that I didn't precise is that I had two Microsoft accounts with the same e-mail address. After having passed to Office 365, I had the second. So I have one account created by me and another created by my organization. The DevOps server is configured with the second one. Anyway, it was working until a certain date. I don't understand.

Comment: I found that https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/unable-to-access-devazurecom/444257 , there are many people having this problem since 2019 but incredibly, there is not a real solution. I am going to try some workaround.